# What's the best way to send a command to every detached tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to get each session to source .tmux.conf.
Is there a built-in way?

Answer (score 1):

.tmux.conf should not be written in such a way that it relies on the session, because it is first run before any sessions are created, so it doesn't really make sense to source it for each session. Just source it once and any global changes will be applied to the server as a whole.

For another config file, it in theory might make sense to have a session so it is used for the default target, but there is currently no way to specify the session to source-file, so you would need to source the file with the session you want as the best session (so from a client attached to the session or a pane only in that session). So not really practical.